# An equivalent to Condition that I can use anonymously when string pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

When I name a pattern I'm working with, that name stands for the same particular expression wherever it shows up. That's a basic precept of how the Wolfram Language's pattern-matching works. But if I want to keep the generality of some pattern, how can I avoid naming it when applying a condition? That's a little hard to articulate, so let me give a specific example.

```
endsWithSpaceQ[str_] := StringEndsQ[str, " "];
str1 = "abc efg 17";
str2 = "abc abc 17";
```

I want to test `str1` and `str2` to see if they match the pattern

```
Repeat[substring-that-satisfies-endsWithSpaceQ, {2}] ~~ "17"
```

It's natural to start with:

```
StringMatchQ[#, 
   Repeated[p__ /; endsWithSpaceQ[p], {2}] ~~ "17"] & /@ {str1, str2}
```

However, this returns `{False, True}`, because since I named the pattern `p__`, *Mathematica* looks for two occurrences of a *particular* string that satisfy my condition. Instead, I want two substrings, not necessarily identical, that satisfy the condition. `?` allows me to use pure functions so I can avoid the necessity for `/; f[]` to take an argument (i.e. the name of my pattern), but `?` does not test an entire substring [sequence for non-string patterns] but rather its individual characters [elements of the sequence].

Is there any way I can use `Condition` without forcing myself to name the pattern? If not, I'm looking specifically for a way to require the anonymous pattern inside `Repeated[__]` to satisfy a condition.

(Help with the title is encouraged -- I can't find anything to sum this question up well)

**Edit: clarification** Of course, my real-life task is a little more complicated than this example. I'm hoping for a general solution or solution-strategy, because I think it'd be good to have on record here. If one isn't out there, I might post another question with my specific problem (assuming I can't hack it together myself).

Comment: Related: [(18337)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18337/121), [(55274)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55274/121), [(86056)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86056/121)

Comment: Thanks for the crossrefs. Two of them I didn't find when searching, which probably means I should brush up on my searching here.

Comment: Searching is difficult which is why as a community service I make these **Related:** comments as often as possible.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for the great job you are doing on this forum! (sorry for ignoring the no thank you rule ;))

Comment: I have yet to see or conceive a universally applicable solution to this issue.  Nevertheless I hope you will post your specific problem so that it can at least serve as an example.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any direct solution to this problem.  I have always had to work around it, but usually I find that isn't too hard.  In this case, as I imagine you know, you could just write:

```
StringMatchQ[#, Repeated[__ ~~ " ", {2}] ~~ "17"] & /@ {str1, str2}
```

> ```
> {True, True}
> ```

Further this is *far* more efficient as it is run in an optimized string library, rather than being done by brute force.

You could of course use multiple patterns, generated programmatically if need be:

```
StringMatchQ[#, (p1__ /; endsWithSpaceQ[p1]) ~~ (p2__ /; endsWithSpaceQ[p2]) ~~ 
    "17"] & /@ {str1, str2}
```

Comment: Unlike in my toy example, the real pattern I'm trying to match repeats an arbitrary number of times, making the prospect of generating patterns programmatically a little scarier. I'll play with it a bit, but seeing that a Wizard doesn't know a general solution to what seems to be a pretty elementary problem suggests that one might not exist and I should start thinking about hacking around the specific case.

Comment: @hYPotenuser Believe me I understand your frustration; this (to the best of my knowledge) is one of those peculiar missing pieces you think should be there but isn't.  If you give a more representative example I might be able to give another recommendation.  Also consider the number of forms that have to be tried; it may be better to abandon pattern matching and parse the string yourself, e.g. `StringSplit` or whatever, then work from there.

Comment: Programmatically you could substitute in `Unique`:
`StringMatchQ[#, 
   StringExpression @@ 
     With[{each = p__ /; endsWithSpaceQ@p}, 
      Table[each /. p -> Unique[], {2}]] ~~ "17"] & /@ {str1, str2}`

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I think here's a way you can do virtually everything you want.

First, my original answer, which I had then moved to a comment to Mr.Wizard's answer.

You can substitute in `Unique`:

> StringMatchQ[#, StringExpression @@ With[{each = p__ /; endsWithSpaceQ@p}, Table[each /. p -> Unique[], {2}]] ~~ "17"] & /@ {str1, str2}
>
> (* {True, True} *)

This gives you what you want for your specific case.

But, you may want to have an arbitrarily long repeated sequence. Meaning, you don't know if it will repeat exactly 2 times or 3 times. The above doesn't do that.

Well, now, I don't know how to do it completely arbitrarily, but if you're willing to choose some maximum, then the following seems to work:

> With[{each = p__ /; endsWithSpaceQ[p]}, 
>    StringMatchQ[#, 
>       Table[StringExpression @@ Table[each /. p -> Unique[], {i}], {i, 
>          10}] ~~ "17"] & /@ {str1, str2}]

(replace the "10" in the last iterator with whatever your maximum is)

The way it works is to first create the sequence of patterns programmatically, as Mr.Wizard suggested. For that, it replicates the "p" pattern a certain `i` number of times and replaces it with a unique symbol each time it appears. Then, the outer table iterates `i` up through the maximum. A list of `StringExpression`'s evaluates as an alternative, so as long as one of those patterns matches, it goes on.

Here's a way to see that it is really working. Let's change your function a little bit:

> endsWithSpaceQn[str_, lenprespace_: 3] := 
>    StringEndsQ[str, " "] && StringLength@str == lenprespace + 1

now we are looking for strings that end with a space and are of length 3 (not counting the space)

Running this:

> With[{each = p__ /; endsWithSpaceQn[p, 3]}, 
>    StringMatchQ[#, 
>       Table[StringExpression @@ Table[each /. p -> Unique[], {i}], {i, 
>          10}] ~~ "17"] & /@ {str1, str2}]

with any maximum greater than 1 in the final iterator (where the `10` is), results in the correct answer:

> (* {True, True} *)

But if you replace the `10` with a `1` then you'll see it comes back as:

> (* {False, False} *)

(if you had used the original `endsWithSpaceQ` function here, it would still come back true, because it would match eg "abc abc ")

Comment: I've been busy with other things and so haven't had a chance to dig in here, but rest assured your answer hasn't been forgotten!

Comment: be sure to consider Mr.Wizard's important point about (in)efficiency and the number of forms this kind of approach implicitly checks: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89160/an-equivalent-to-condition-that-i-can-use-anonymously-when-string-pattern-matchi/89170?noredirect=1#comment243444_89161